# how to apply count condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql

2,0 - open ,  2,1 - Pending ,  2,2 - closed

Need suggestion to find out all tickets which are open again after once closed(2,2)

```
id   c_id  type   value  created_at

1    201    2       0     
2    201    2       1
3    201    2       2
4    201    2       0
5    201    2       2
6    201    2       0
7    201    2       1
8    201    2       2
```

Comment: How do we determine that an `open` is "after" a `close`? By a higher value of the `id` column? (Typically, we use the value in a datetime or timestamp column to tell if one event is "after" another event.)

Comment: yeah..we have id and created_at in table..i tried select * from table where c_id=201 and id IN(select min(id) from table where c_id=201 and type=2 and value=2) and Open/Pending condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id IN(
    SELECT id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE type = 2
    AND value = 2
    )
AND type != 2
AND value != 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `c_id` is the identifier of a ticket, and assuming that the `id` column is used to determine that one event is "after" another event...

```
SELECT o.c_id
  FROM mytable o        -- open events
  JOIN mytable c        -- close events
    ON c.c_id = o.c_id  -- match same ticket
   AND c.type = 2 
   AND c.value = 2      -- close event
   AND c.id < o.id      -- close event is before open
 WHERE o.type = 2 
   AND o.value = 0      -- open event
 GROUP BY o.c_id        -- distinct list of ticket
```